# NSolve Evaluated Too Early Inside NExpectation

Tags: equation-solving, functions, numerical-integration

**Motivation / Context**

I'm working on an economic model which, for present purposes, we can think of as a mapping from parameters to results. Some of the parameters are fixed and given, while others are assumed to be random variables with a known distribution. I would like to calculate the expected value of the results of the model.

**Structure of Problem**

I've written a simpler outline of my project, which preserves the structure of my approach. `var1` is constant that I choose, while `var2` has a Log Normal distribution. Given `var1` and `var2`, I have an equation in one variable that I solve using `NSolve`. I want to calculate the expectation of `soln` (the solution to the equation) over the distribution of `var2` using `NExpectation`. I can get this to work when the equation solved by `NSolve` can be solved symbolically, but not when it cannot. I think this happens because `NSolve` is evaluated before being mapped over whatever table of values is used for numerical integration.

**Working Example of Problem**

```
(*Example of the problem*)
Clear[dBeta, solnEquation, solnFun, modelMoment];

dBeta[k_Integer, x_, var1_] = 
  Derivative[k, 0][Beta[#1, #2, 2] &][x, var1];
solnEquation[var1_, var2_, x_] := 
  Sum[Binomial[5, k]*dBeta[k, x, var1]*var2^k, {k, 0, 5}];

solnFun[var1_, var2_] := 
  x /. NSolve[
      solnEquation[var1, var2, x] == Beta[var1, 2] && 0 < x < 1, x, 
      Reals][[1]][[1]];

modelMoment[var1_, mu_, sigma_] := 
  NExpectation[solnFun[var1, var2], 
   Distributed[var2, LogNormalDistribution[mu, sigma]]];

solnFun[2, 1/10]
testMoment[2, 1/10, 1/20]

(*Variation with no problem *)
Clear[solnEquation, solnFun]
solnEquation[var1_, var2_, x_] := var1 - var2 + x;

solnFun[var1_, var2_] := 
  x /. NSolve[solnEquation[var1, var2, x] == 0, x, Reals][[1]][[1]];

solnFun[2, 1/10]
testMoment[2, 1/10, 1/20]
```

output below

```
0.328152 
This system cannot be solved with the methods available to NSolve. 
{-20 var2^3+10 var2^2 (1-2 x)+5 var2 (1-x) x+Beta[x,2,2]==1/6} is
neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and 
so cannot be used for replacing. 
... 
"Further output of \!\(\* StyleBox[RowBox[{\"ReplaceAll\", \"::\", \"reps\"}], \"MessageName\"]\) will 
be suppressed during this calculation." 
NExpectation[  x /. -20 var2^3 + 10 var2^2 (1 - 2 x) + 5 var2 (1 - x) x + 
    Beta[x, 2, 2] == 1/6,   var2 \[Distributed] LogNormalDistribution[1/10, 1/20]]

-1.9
-0.893447
```

In both cases, `solnFun` can be evaluated successfully. In the first case, the `NExpectation` attempt fails, in the second case, it works. I think the difference between the two examples is that the `NSolve` inside of `SolnFun` is evaluated before any specific values for `var2` are given to it by `NExpectation`. If a closed form solution exists for symbolic equation, then no error messages appear. But in my project `NSolve` cannot provide a solution until after it has a specific value for `var2`.

**Question**

Is there some way I can get `NSolve` to be evaluated *after* the equation has been mapped over whatever table of values `NExpectation` uses to perform the numeric integration?

I'm new to MMA, so in addition to help with this main problem, I would appreciate any other tips or references on better programming style or approaches.

Comment: Could you provide some code that reproduces the problem (i.e. a simple example without a "symbolic closed form expression")? It sounds like a [NumericQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/1024) issue.

Comment: @Pragabhava I changed `solnEquation` so that it now reproduces the problem. I was hoping to find a simpler example completely different from my project, but failed to do so after about an hour of trying various things. So instead I just tried to simplify the function I am working with in my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pragabhava](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1024/pragabhava)'s [guess](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/139193/nsolve-evaluated-too-early-inside-nexpectation#comment375876_139193) is correct: it is indeed the well-known [`_?NumericQ`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/280) issue.

Basically you need to define `solnFun` as `solnFun[var1_?NumberQ, var2_?NumberQ] := ...`. Incorporating also a [workaround for `NSolve` bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/140376/280), your code can be rewritten as follows:

```
Clear[dBeta, solnEquation, solnFun];

dBeta[k_Integer, x_, var1_] = Derivative[k, 0][Beta[#1, #2, 2] &][x, var1];
solnEquation[var1_, var2_, x_] = Sum[Binomial[5, k]*dBeta[k, x, var1]*var2^k, {k, 0, 5}];
equation[var1_, var2_, x_] := solnEquation[var1, var2, x] == Beta[2, 2];

solnFun[var1_?NumberQ, var2_?NumberQ] := 
 x /. NSolve[FunctionExpand[equation[2, 1/10, x]] && 0 < x < 1, x, Reals][[1]][[1]];

modelMoment[var1_, mu_, sigma_] := 
  NExpectation[solnFun[var1, var2], Distributed[var2, LogNormalDistribution[mu, sigma]]];
```

Now

```
modelMoment[2, 1/10, 1/20]
```

> ```
> 0.328152
> ```