# NSolve claims there are no solutions in Reals but finds them without restriction to Reals

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, special-functions, backslide

When trying to answer [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/139193/280) question I've discovered what looks like a bug in `NSolve` introduced in version 11.1.0.

```
$Version
```

> ```
> "11.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 13, 2017)"
> ```

With setup

```
Clear[dBeta, solnEquation, solnFun];

dBeta[k_Integer, x_, var1_] = Derivative[k, 0][Beta[#1, #2, 2] &][x, var1];
solnEquation[var1_, var2_, x_] = Sum[Binomial[5, k]*dBeta[k, x, var1]*var2^k, {k, 0, 5}];
equation[var1_, var2_, x_] := solnEquation[var1, var2, x] == Beta[2, 2];
```

`Solve` is able to find two solutions for `var1 = 2`, `var2 = 1/10`:

```
sol = Solve[equation[2, 1/10, x] && 0 < x < 1, x, Reals];
equation[2, 1/10, x] /. Normal@sol // N
```

> Solve::incs: Warning: Solve was unable to prove that the solution set found is complete.
>
> ```
> {True, True}
> ```

While `NSolve` claims that there are no solutions in the real domain:

```
NSolve[equation[2, 1/10, x] && 0 < x < 1, x, Reals]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

But without this restriction it finds two solutions in the real domain:

```
NSolve[equation[2, 1/10, x] && 0 < x < 1, x]
equation[2, 1/10, x] /. %
```

> ```
> {{x -> 0.328152}, {x -> 0.741041}}
>
> {True, True}
> ```

In version 11.0.1 `NSolve` gives correct answer for the real domain:

```
$Version
```

> ```
> "11.0.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (September 20, 2016)"
> ```

```
NSolve[equation[2, 1/10, x] && 0 < x < 1, x, Reals]
```

> ```
> {{x -> 0.3281517106189123`}, {x -> 0.7410414526199698`}}
> ```

Is it a bug in version 11.1.0?

Answer (score 2):

A possible cure for your problem is to use `FunctionExpand[]` to ensure that the incomplete beta function is expanded to the actual polynomial it represents. Thus:

```
NSolve[FunctionExpand[equation[2, 1/10, x]] && 0 < x < 1, x, Reals]
   {{x -> 0.3281517106189123}, {x -> 0.7410414526199698}}
```

Comment: Should we tag this as a bug?

Comment: It's certainly a regression.

Answer (score 1):

This is a precision issue

```
$Version

(* "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)" *)

Clear[dBeta, solnEquation, solnFun];

dBeta[k_Integer, x_, var1_] = Derivative[k, 0][Beta[#1, #2, 2] &][x, var1];
solnEquation[var1_, var2_, x_] = 
  Sum[Binomial[5, k]*dBeta[k, x, var1]*var2^k, {k, 0, 5}];
equation[var1_, var2_, x_] := solnEquation[var1, var2, x] == Beta[2, 2];

sol = Solve[equation[2, 1/10, x] && 0 < x < 1, x, Reals];
```

Note that using machine precision the imaginary parts are only approximately zero.

```
sol // N

(* {{x -> ConditionalExpression[0.328152 + 0. I, 
    0.0420629 + 0. I ∈ Reals]}, {x -> 
   ConditionalExpression[0.741041 + 0. I, 0.138925 + 0. I ∈ Reals]}} *)
```

The solutions are exact

```
equation[2, 1/10, x] /. sol // FullSimplify

(* {True, True} *)
```

However, when using [`NSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html) for this problem you cannot use machine precision. Use arbirary-precision by specifying the [`WorkingPrecision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html)

```
NSolve[equation[2, 1/10, x] && 0 < x < 1, x, Reals, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 15]

(* {{x -> 0.328151710618912}, {x -> 0.741041452619970}} *)
```

**EDIT:** Alternatively, since 0 < x < 1`implies that`x` is real just use

```
NSolve[equation[2, 1/10, x] && 0 < x < 1, x]

(* {{x -> 0.328152}, {x -> 0.741041}} *)
```